# Pydantic model not including fields defined inside itself

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi, pydantic

I have a `BaseSchema` and `BaseDocument` models that define necessary configuration for two types of models (one for application request-response side of things, and the other is for defining MongoDB documents using `beanie`) that I am going to use in my app. For a simple setting, I have made my models like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from typing import Any

from beanie import Document
from pydash import camel_case
from pydantic import BaseModel, Extra


def format_datetime_into_isoformat(timestamp: datetime) -> str:
    return timestamp.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).isoformat().replace("+00:00", "Z")


def format_dict_key_to_camel_case(key: str) -> str:
    return camel_case(key)


class BaseDocument(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        orm_mode: bool = True
        use_enum_values: bool = True
        validate_assignment: bool = True
        allow_population_by_field_name: bool = True
        json_encoders: dict = {datetime: format_datetime_into_isoformat}


class BaseSchema(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        extra = Extra.forbid
        allow_population_by_field_name: bool = True
        alias_generator: Any = format_dict_key_to_camel_case


class UserBase(BaseDocument):
    user_name: str
    email: str
    password: str


class User(Document, UserBase):
    class Settings:
        name = "users"
        indexes = ["user_name", "email"]


class UserAPI(BaseSchema, UserBase):
    _id: str
```

the problem is, when I try to use the `UserAPI` model, it only contains the fields defined on the `UserBase` model, but not the `_id` field that I defined in the model itself. I am unable to figure out what's going on with the inheritence here, but I am pretty sure that the fields defined in the model itself should have priority over any other fields in the models it inherited from and even override the ones having common names. Anyone knows what's wrong here?

I have also printed the schema for the `UserAPI` model, it outputs as such:

```
{'title': 'UserAPI', 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'userName': {'title': 'Username', 'type': 'string'}, 'email': {'title': 'Email', 'type': 'string'}, 'password': {'title': 'Password', 'type': 'string'}}, 'required': ['userName', 'email', 'password'], 'additionalProperties': False}
```

I am expecting to have a `UserBase` which will define the general schema, and `User` model which will map a MongoDB collection using `beanie` and it will inherit both `Document` and `UserBase` (this part works perfectly fine). And then I want to have a `UserAPI` model which will add another field on top of `UserBase` so that I can have the ids with my output after a record is saved in MongoDB collection.

Answer (score 1):

The underscore in from the "id" makes it a class attribute and excludes it from the model. Pydantic info [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#automatically-excluded-attributes)

You can work around this by calling the attribute "id" and use an alias with an underscore

```py
from pydantic import Field

class UserAPI(BaseSchema, UserBase):
    id: ObjectId = Field(None, alias="_id", title="Primary key", description="mongodb's Primary key")
```

inspiration from [this](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/2105#issuecomment-818646999)

Comment: I am using this model for taking request body and as response model in a fastapi setup, this approach has worked for other use cases, but it seems I need a different approach for making it comply with fastapi, and I am also trying to make the `_id` to be included in json as `id`.